# Vuelidate pass array to not sameAs

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Ok I hope this has a simple solution.
I am trying to make a validation with Vuelidate on a field to be different than an array of strings.
So - sending a single string is working: `not(sameAs(() =>"hello"))`
But trying to send an array or comma seperated values wont validate anymore :`not(sameAs(() => ["hello", "helloo"]))` or `not(sameAs(() => "hello", "helloo"))`.
Hopefully someone can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright if anyone is interested - 
I just created my own validator ->
`usedTitles:['hello','helloo'];`

`const checkDuplicates = () => this.usedTitles.indexOf(this.val) === -1;
val.unique = checkDuplicates;`